# How to use delimiter to exclude parenthesis?

Tags: java, parsing, data-structures, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Say I have this string: "(hello) (world)"

How would I use the .useDelimiter() method to get an output that prints hello and world in separate lines?

I saw a bunch of delimiter pattern examples and they all seem to use a weird syntax inside the useDelimiter's parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "weird syntax" is called regular expression, you can find the syntax in the [javadoc of the class Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

The default delimiter is `\p{javaWhitespace}+` which means one ore more "java whitespace" (see the previous javadoc).

In your case, you can change it to `[\p{javaWhitespace}()]+` since you have spaces too.

Also don't forget to escape the `\p`

```
s.useDelimiter("[\\p{javaWhitespace}()]+");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I believe I found the pattern I wanted to ignore all punctuation: "\p{Punct}", but I'm not sure to write the pattern to include this and whitespace together.

Comment: Just put it in `[]` with a space like `[\\p{Punct} ]+`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this delimiter :

```
 "\\(|\\)"
```

Answer (score 0):

`useDelimiter()` accepts a regular expression as its argument, you can check out Oracle's tutorial on regular expressions here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

For your specific case, the delimiter `[\\(\\)]` should work.